# django and stripe subscription payments issues

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a subscription based saas in django. There are three subscription tiers with both monthly and annual payment options. I have setup the stripe customer id to be created when a new user signs up.

I have somehow managed to put together the forms so that they redirect to Stripe's checkout, but I can't save the subscription id and the subscription end date in the database. I get an error as well "An error occurred while creating the new subscription: Request req_8TXfavfNXo1P0A: This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method. Please consider adding a default payment method. For more information, visit [https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment-methods-setting#payment-method-priority."](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment-methods-setting#payment-method-priority.%22)

I want to be able to save the subscription id and subscription end date after a successful payment.

My models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save

    import stripe
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    User = get_user_model()



    MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Free', 'free'),
    ('Basic', 'basic'),
    ('Premium', 'premium')
)


    class Membership(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)
    stripe_monthly_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    stripe_yearly_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)

    price_monthly = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price_yearly = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type
    
    class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    subscription_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    class MembershipMetadata(models.Model):
    membership = models.OneToOneField(Membership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tokens = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    features = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Metadata for {self.membership.membership_type}"
    
    def post_save_usermembership_create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

        if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
            user_membership.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
            
        # Set the default membership type here
        user_membership.membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
        user_membership.save()

    post_save.connect(post_save_usermembership_create, sender=User)



    class Subscription(models.Model):
    user_membership = models.ForeignKey(UserMembership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_membership.user.username
```

my views.py

```
import stripe
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
from django.views.generic import ListView, View
from .models import Membership, UserMembership
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json


stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:8000'

def get_user_membership(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            user_membership = UserMembership.objects.get(user=request.user)
            print("User Membership Retrieved:", user_membership)
            return user_membership
        except UserMembership.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    return None



class MembershipSelectView(ListView):
    model = Membership
    template_name = 'memberships/membership_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'memberships'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Membership.objects.select_related('membershipmetadata').all().order_by('ordering')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        current_membership = get_user_membership(self.request)
        context['current_membership'] = current_membership
    
        for membership in context['memberships']:
            membership.metadata_features = membership.membershipmetadata.features.split(',')
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        selected_membership_type = request.POST.get('membership_type')
        user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

        selected_membership_qs = Membership.objects.filter(
            membership_type=selected_membership_type)

        if selected_membership_qs.exists():
            selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()



class PaymentView(View):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        selected_membership_type = request.POST.get('membership_type')
        billing_cycle = request.POST.get('billing_cycle')
        user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

        print("Form Data - Selected Membership Type:", selected_membership_type)
        print("Form Data - Billing Cycle:", billing_cycle)

        if not selected_membership_type or not user_membership:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid membership selection. Please select a valid membership.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

        selected_membership = Membership.objects.filter(membership_type=selected_membership_type).first()

        print("Selected Membership:", selected_membership)

        if not selected_membership:
            messages.error(request, "Selected membership type does not exist.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

        # Determine the price and billing period based on the selected membership and billing cycle
        if billing_cycle == 'monthly':
            price = selected_membership.price_monthly
            plan_id = selected_membership.stripe_monthly_plan_id
        else:
            price = selected_membership.price_yearly
            plan_id = selected_membership.stripe_yearly_plan_id

        print("Price:", price)
        print("Plan ID:", plan_id)

        request.session['selected_membership_type'] = selected_membership_type


        # Create a Stripe Checkout Session for subscription payment
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                line_items=[{
                    'price': plan_id,  # Use the appropriate Stripe plan ID based on billing_cycle
                    'quantity': 1,
                }],
                mode='subscription',
                success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + reverse('memberships:success'),  # Replace 'success' with your success URL
                cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + reverse('memberships:cancel'),  # Replace 'cancel' with your cancel URL
                customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
            )

            # Redirect the user to the Stripe Checkout page for subscription payment
            return HttpResponseRedirect(checkout_session.url)

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Handle any Stripe API errors
            messages.error(request, f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle any other unexpected errors
            messages.error(request, "An unexpected error occurred while processing your payment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))



class PaymentSuccessView(View):
    def get_price_id(self, membership, billing_cycle):
        if billing_cycle == 'monthly':
            return membership.stripe_monthly_plan_id
        elif billing_cycle == 'yearly':
            return membership.stripe_yearly_plan_id
        else:
            return None

    def get_subscription_end_date(self, subscription):
        # Convert the current_period_end timestamp to a Python datetime object
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription.current_period_end)

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        selected_membership_type = request.session.get('selected_membership_type')
        billing_cycle = request.session.get('billing_cycle')

        if not selected_membership_type or not billing_cycle:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid payment details. Please try again.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

        try:
            selected_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type=selected_membership_type)
        except Membership.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "Selected membership type does not exist.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

        # Get the user's current UserMembership
        user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

        # Update the user's membership to the selected one
        user_membership.membership = selected_membership
        user_membership.save()

        # Create a new Stripe subscription
        try:
            # Get the price ID based on the selected billing cycle
            price_id = self.get_price_id(selected_membership, billing_cycle)

            if not price_id:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid billing cycle.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

            # Create a new subscription in Stripe
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user_membership.stripe_customer_id)
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=customer,
                items=[{
                    'price': price_id,
                }],
            )

            # Save the subscription ID and subscription end date in the database
            user_membership.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
            user_membership.subscription_end_date = self.get_subscription_end_date(subscription)
            user_membership.save()

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            if e.code == 'customer_has_no_default_payment_method':
                messages.error(request, "Please add a default payment method to your Stripe account.")
            else:
                messages.error(request, f"An error occurred while creating the new subscription: {str(e)}")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, "An unexpected error occurred while creating the new subscription.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:select'))

        # Clear the session data as it's no longer needed
        del request.session['selected_membership_type']
        del request.session['billing_cycle']

        # Optionally, you can set a message for the user about the updated membership type
        messages.success(request, f"Membership updated to {selected_membership_type} successfully!")

        # Render the success template and pass the updated membership type as a context variable
        return render(request, 'memberships/success.html', {'updated_membership_type': selected_membership_type})
```

the html form

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Choose Your Plan</h1>
  <div class="row">
      <h2>Monthly Plans</h2>
      {% for membership in memberships %}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <h2>{{ membership.membership_type }}</h2>
          <p>${{ membership.price_monthly }}<small>/Month</small></p>
          <p>{{ membership.membershipmetadata.description }}</p>
          <strong>Features</strong><br>
          {{ membership.membershipmetadata.features|linebreaks }}
          
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'memberships:payment' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="membership_type" value="{{ membership.membership_type }}">
              <input type="hidden" name="billing_cycle" value="monthly"> <!-- Add billing_cycle input for monthly form -->
              {% if current_membership and membership.membership_type == current_membership.membership.membership_type %}
                  <small>You are already on this plan.</small>
              {% else %}
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Select Monthly Plan</button>
              {% endif %}
          </form>
          {% else %}
              <!-- Show the Sign Up button for non-logged-in users -->
              <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to add another html form for the yearly options and allow users to toggle to choose either option.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Kindly provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've removed the payment cancel view and left the rest so you can understand the context. I'm a newbie, so I mostly just put stuff together from tutorials